# echo with ajax does't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was following an tutorial, and i finish with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function($){
      $("#compila").click(function(){
          var code = $(#codigo).html();

          $.post("myajax.php",{code:code},function(return){
            $(#result).html("<b>print </b>"+return);
          });
      });
    });

</script>

<?php
      $code = $_POST["code"];
      echo $code;

 ?>
```

but this code doesn't work. I was using a text area, and i'm trying to send a string of the text area to a

tag, and print with echo of the php. How i can fix this code?

Comment: `$('#codigo')` use it with `"` or `'`

Comment: same for `$(#result)`

Comment: `$('#result').html("<b>print </b>"+return);`  you forget to add quotes around `#result`

Comment: Learn to make use of your browser console, it will tell you about stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotes around some of your identifiers:

```
var code = $(#codigo).html();
```

should be

```
var code = $("#codigo").html();
```

and

```
$(#result).html("<b>print </b>"+return);
```

should be

```
$("#result").html("<b>print </b>"+return);
```

If you use the developer console in your browser (<kbd>F12</kbd> and go to the console tab) it should then tell you about these errors and give you the line number of where the errors occur.

As [userr1T77](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4286807/userr1t77) mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44965712/1561469), you need to change the variable name from `return` to something else. `return` is a reserved keyword so can't be used as a variable, so your code should be something similar to

```
$.post("myajax.php",{code:code},function(return_data){
    $("#result").html("<b>print </b>"+return_data);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Apart from missing the quotes in you selectors you shouldn't use the reserved word `return` for a variable.